# Matlab - customize surface color depending on a parameter

Tags: matlab, colors, patch, mesh, geometry-surface

I have a problem in customizing colors of a surface plot (trisurf or trimesh).

I would like every face to have a color depending on the relative strain value (calculated for every triangle of the mesh). I was thinking about something like:

```
p = patch('Faces',faces,'Vertices',verts,'FaceColor',strain);
```

But `FaceColor` seems not to work with arrays.

strain is an array of `Nx1` where `N` is the number of faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change `FaceColor` to `'flat'` to enable colours to be read from a color-data array - the `CData` property:

Try this (not tested though):

```
p = patch( ...
   'Faces',     faces, ...
   'Vertices',  verts, ...
   'FaceColor', 'flat', ...
   'CData',     strain' ...
);
```

Here I set the `CData` property to the transpose of your `strain` vector. MATLAB should then automatically map the N strain-values in this vector to the chosen colormap (linearly). See property `CDataMapping` for more information:

Documentation:

http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/patch_props.html#FaceColor
http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/patch_props.html#CData
http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/patch_props.html#CDataMapping